# UsageStatsManager along with BookmarkColumns on Sdk Version 23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

In API 23 the `android.provider.Browser.BookmarkColumns` package was removed and instead `UsageStatsManager` was placed. While on the other hand `UsageStatsManager` isn't available for APIs prior to 23.

Also, checking the sdk version using `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` doesn't work since the packages themselves aren't present.

How can one use both, the `UsageStatsManager` as well as the `BookmarkColums` on CompileSdkVersion 23? Can this be achieved by having versions of app, one version having `UsageStatsManager` and the other one having `BookmarkColumns`, how? What would be the proper way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay! Figured it out. If anyone else wants to do the same, instead of using compileSdk as 23 or 21 use `22`. It has both UsageStatsManager as well as BookmarkColumns packages.

And for checking build version at run time use `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` and call the appropriate package as required.